# Can't register new users

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a problem registering new users on my page.
I'm using a REST API with nodejs, express and the sequelize ORM.
The problem is that I am unable to register new users and the only error I get is that the time for the request has expired.

This is the method in controller:

```
async store(req, res) {
    try {
      const novoUser = await User.create(req.body);

      const { id, nome, email } = novoUser;
      res.json({ id, nome, email });
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(400).json({
        errors: e.errors.map((err) => err.message),
      });
    }
  }
```

The route file:

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import userController from '../controllers/User';
import loginRequired from '../middlewares/loginRequired';
import userDeleteController from '../controllers/UserDelete';

const router = new Router();

router.post('/', userController.store); // creates users
router.get('/', loginRequired, userController.usersList); // List all users, with all their data
router.get('/:useremail', loginRequired, userController.search); // Get a user's data
router.put('/:id', loginRequired, userController.update); // Updates user data (except email)
router.put('/:useremail', loginRequired, userController.userBan); // Ban a user (remove access to the page but not delete the account)
router.delete('/:id', loginRequired, userDeleteController.delete); // Deletes a user and their data

export default router;
```

[The error in insomnia:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L16nB.png)

I need the users whose data I send to the API to be registered but the timeout for the request is reached and I don't know the reason for this.
I reviewed my code several times and didn't find any errors and I also didn't find anyone with this same problem.
Thank you to anyone who can help!

Comment: Where have you mounted `router`. You are posting to `/user` so I assume `app.use('/user', router)`?

Comment: The route was referenced in the app.js file, like this:

Comment: ` this.app.use('/users/', userRoutes); ` userRoutes is the name the file received when it was imported into app.js

Comment: You will need to post the code from `app.js` into your question so that I can see the full picture. Also, do a `console.log('caught: ', e)` as the first statement within that `catch (e)` block. Look at your terminal to see what was logged.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I used console.log as you said and discovered that the problem was that I was trying to register users without entering the value of one of the database fields.
I changed this configuration in the migration and model and the problem was resolved.

Comment: Congrats. Sounds like you did your own successful debugging. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `return` into the store function.
Like this:

```
async store(req, res) {
  try {
     const novoUser = await User.create(req.body);

     const { id, nome, email } = novoUser;
     return res.json({ id, nome, email });
   } catch (e) {
     return res.status(400).json({
       errors: e.errors.map((err) => err.message),
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried but the error persists